# How to add rank, based on points in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am struggle with mysql query. please help me.
This is my query, i getting correct result but i need to modify the result in mysql.

```
                SELECT  bu.username,
                    bg.id as goal_id,
                    br.id as reason_id,
                    (SELECT COUNT(test_reason_id) FROM test_rank WHERE test_reason_id = br.id) as point
                FROM
                    test_goal AS bg INNER JOIN test_reason AS br ON 
                    br.user_id=bg.user_id INNER JOIN test_user AS bu ON
                    br.user_id=bu.id
                WHERE
                    bg.id       =   br.test_goal_id
                GROUP BY
                    bg.id
                ORDER BY
                    point DESC
```

**Tabble-1**
My actual table look like this when i use ORDER BY point DESC then its look like **Table-2**

```
username     goal_id    reason_id   point
 khan           8            3        2
 john           6            9        5
 yoyo           5           21        4
 smith         11            6        5
```

**Tabble-2**
My result set look like this

```
username     goal_id    reason_id   point
 john           6            9        5
 smith         11            6        5
 yoyo           5           21        4
 khan           8            3        2
```

But i want my result set like this

```
username     goal_id    reason_id   point   rank
 john           6            9        5       1
 smith         11            6        5       2
 yoyo           5           21        4       3
 khan           8            3        2       4
```

is this possible? please can any one help me. it too difficult for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a row count variable like this:

```
select a.*,  (@row := @row + 1) as rank
from (
      SELECT  bu.username,
                bg.id as goal_id,
                br.id as reason_id,
                (SELECT COUNT(test_reason_id) FROM test_rank WHERE test_reason_id = br.id) as point                   
            FROM
                test_goal AS bg INNER JOIN test_reason AS br ON 
                br.user_id=bg.user_id INNER JOIN test_user AS bu ON
                br.user_id=bu.id                    
            WHERE
                bg.id       =   br.test_goal_id
            GROUP BY
                bg.id
            ORDER BY
                point DESC
) a, (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

See [this simplified SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c465d/11)

Comment: :( rank not working properly. i need ORDER BY point DESC and rank ASC.

Comment: Please now see question again I changed little bit. is my question clear?

Comment: @yogi46: I edited my answer. The `order by` changes the row count which is applied before. Now the rank will be build after the `orderby`